# Find and rename forward slash in directory name (Linux / OmniOS)?

Tags: linux, command-line, find, rename, mv

On a fileserver at work, we have a bunch of old directories made on macOS (that was previously on an AFP share) that has `/` in the name. I would like to replace `/` with `-`, but am having a hard time doing that. Also some of the directories also contain `<space>` that complicates things even further.

Example directories with forward slash:

- `Brief/Debrief` (shows up as `Brief:Debrief` in Linux cli)
- `Til/fra kunde` (shows up as `Til:Fra kunder` in Linux cli)

I would like to rename them to be `Brief-Debrief` and `Til-Fra kunde`, i.e replacing `/` with `-`

I have tried with `find` and `-exec mv …` on OmniOS, but I have not managed to get the forward slash (and especially not when there is a `<space>` in the name also.

I can use an Ubuntu VM that access the share via NFS, and there I have access to rename, etc., but I'm still having issues.

Any input on how to solve this?

**EDIT:**

As per @Kamil Maciorowski suggestion, all I needed to look for was `:`, and presto.

Final command:

`find . -name "*:*" -type d -execdir rename -n 's/:/-/g' "{}" \;`

(remove the `-n` flag if you copy this, `-n` = dry run)

Comment: "there I have access to rename, etc., but I'm still having issues" — which issues? Please specify what you did and what the result was.

Comment: I have tried so many things, that I'm not even sure any more.

ie. `find . -name "*\/*" -type d
find: warning: Unix filenames usually don't contain slashes (though pathnames do).  That means that '-name '*\\/*'' will probably evaluate to false all the time on this system.  You might find the '-wholename' test more useful, or perhaps '-samefile'.  Alternatively, if you are using GNU grep, you could use 'find ... -print0 | grep -FzZ '*\\/*''.`

Comment: If the entry shows up as `Brief:Debrief`, can you refer to it as (literally) `Brief:Debrief`? Like `mv 'Brief:Debrief' 'Brief-Debrief'`?

Comment: Yes, actually. That worked. I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to use `/` as a search key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Kamil Maciorowski suggestion, all I needed to look for was `:`, and presto.

Final command:

`find . -name "*:*" -type d -execdir rename -n 's/:/-/g' "{}" \;`

(remove the `-n` flag if you copy this, `-n` = dry run)